# Adding notepad as my inner window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm new to Windows Programming and am trying to create a window and have Notepad be an inner window of the parent.

Right now I have something like this:

```
HWND parent = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              
    L"Class name",                     
    L"Some Text",    
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL,       
    NULL,       
    hInstance,  
    NULL        
    );
```

Of course I `RegisterClass` and all that good stuff first. What I would like to do is be able to call something like:

```
HINSTANCE child = ShellExecute(
    parent,
    L"open",
    L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    5
    );
ShowWindow(parent, 5);
```

but that will open Notepad in a new window and leave the parent as a seperate window.
I'm thinking I may need to add this support in the draw command but at the same time I don't think it would be necessary to try to draw an .exe as an inner window everytime a draw is requested.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Notepad is just a simple textbox control and a menu - you can just create the same in C++ with little work. Trying to host a window from another process is _very, very hard_ to say the least (if it's even possible - I'm unsure of this (but 99% sure)).

Comment: @xxbbcc, I'm trying to get a 3rd party application hosted as an inner window from the parent window I create. Notepad is just what I'm trying it with.

Comment: You can try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101367/Code-to-Host-a-Third-Party-Application-in-our-Proc

Comment: Last time I tried this, I ran into all kinds of weird problems (I tried it with Word, years ago). The tightened security in Windows 7 and Windows 8 may make this a lot harder to do. The problem is not with doing it but to get a consistent user experience.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to do this.  I'm not saying it's impossible, but there's no supported method.

Comment: This isn't likely to work out. It might work. Or it might not. Depends on whether or not the other app plays ball. You also need to be something of a Win32 ninja. Which I suspect that you are not yet. Why don't you try a different solution to whatever your problem is?

Comment: I tried that C# project but using C++ I still get the same result. I'm not sure what other solutions there are. I need to get an .exe to be hosted by a parent window that I create. Different language?

Comment: Why do you want to host Notepad? Is there something a normal multiline edit control cannot accomplish?

Comment: @ZWiki: *why* do you want the other application's window to be inside your parent window?  Have you considered that this may not really be necessary?

Comment: You should consider other solutions to your problem

Comment: I'm trying to host multiple 3rd party applications in a tabbed window, Notepad is just what I was using to test it with as I mentioned above. I know there's other solutions like having a master window control slave windows but I figured I would give this a shot